# What is uniform convergence for one function and how is that equivalent to continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

My teacher wanted to prove that function

$$\frac{1}{x} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{n^2-x^2}$$

is continuous. He said that it is equivalent to proving that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$$

uniformly converges. However uniform convergence is defined for a sequence of function as I understand it. Here I see only one function: the equation depends purely on x and nothing else than x - that is just one function in terms of x.

But even if it made sense, how is uniform convergence equivalent to continuity?

According to my knowledge he didn't even prove uniform convergence (despite saying that). He only proved that the equation above:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$$

converges (to a number smaller than something). And convergence (as I understand it) is different from uniform convergence.

How is that correct?

Comment: Your teacher talks about the sequence of functions $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$

Comment: Thank you this actually makes sense. But still if I prove it converges, the whole function converges but why is it continuos?

Comment: If you are familiar with metric spaces:  Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e)$ be non-empty metric spaces.Def'n:  A sequence $(f_n)_n$ of functions from  $ X$ to $Y$ converges uniformly to $f:X\to Y$ iff $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{p\in X} e(\;f(p),f_n(p)\;)=0.$... Theorem: If each $ f_n$ is continuous and $(f_n)_n$  converges uniformly to $f$,  then $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem: the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions on an interval is a continuous function on that interval.

If you examine the teacher's proof that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 - x^2}$ converges (presumably on some interval that doesn't contain any positive integer $n$), it may have in it some estimate that is true for all 
$x$ in the interval.  That will allow you to conclude that the convergence is
uniform.

Comment: Yes, this explains everything. Had no idea about the theorem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A little addendum: not only such function is continuous on its maximal domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$, but it is a well-known function. If we start with the Weierstrass product for the sine function
$$ \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)\tag{1} $$
and apply $\frac{d}{dx}\log(\cdot)$ to both sides we get:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2x}{x^2-n^2} = \pi\cot(\pi x)-\frac{1}{x}\tag{2} $$
hence:
$$ \frac{1}{x}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2x}{n^2-x^2} = \color{red}{\pi\cot(\pi x)}.\tag{3} $$

Comment: Yes, this is the reason my teacher was talking about the function in the first place, but thanks.